# Executing script through javascriptExecutor

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, webdriver

I want to get the following javascript executed to be executed in java webdriver. I am using `javascriptExecutor`.

```
String script = "props();"
    + "function props(){"
    + "var b = document.querySelector("+ WE +");"
    + "var properties = [];"
    + "for(var k in b){"
    + "properties.push(k);"
    + "properties.sort();}"
    + "return properties;}";

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript(script);
```

and when i execute it i get the following exception
`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: missing ] after element list`

Comment: Try printing the output of script variable in the console and copy and paste that in the browser's console and execute the script and see if it throws an error.

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro its giving the error

SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

Comment: What is the value of the variable `WE`? I think that maybe causing an error in your script.

Comment: Yes the problem was with WE, i have resolved it. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should read the guide [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)